# Refresh Kendo dropdownlist after event change of another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

When I change the value from the first ddl I get the data from Ajax of the other ddl but it doesnt refresh.

This is my grid

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: 
height: 500,
                toolbar: ["create"],
                columns: [
                     { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "150px", locked: true },
                    { field: "RowLabels", title: "Row Labels", width: "180px", locked: true },
                    { field: "IdValueStream", title: "VS", width: "90px", locked: true, editor: vsDropDownEditor, template: "#=getVsName(IdValueStream)#" }, //, template: "#=IdValueStream.ValueStream#"
                    { field: "IdLine", title: "Line", width: "180px", locked: true, editor: linesDropDownEditor }, //, template: "#=getLineName(IdLine)#" 
                       { field: "W1", title: Weeks[0].W1.substring(0, 10), width: "98px" }, // 
                       { field: "W2", title: Weeks[0].W2.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W3", title: Weeks[0].W3.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W4", title: Weeks[0].W4.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W5", title: Weeks[0].W5.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W6", title: Weeks[0].W6.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W7", title: Weeks[0].W7.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W8", title: Weeks[0].W8.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W9", title: Weeks[0].W9.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W10", title: Weeks[0].W10.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W11", title: Weeks[0].W11.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W12", title: Weeks[0].W12.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" },
                       { field: "W13", title: Weeks[0].W13.substring(0, 10), width: "90px" }
                ],
                editable: "inline"
            });
```

This is the method from the editor of the first ddl

```
function vsDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input id="ddlVs" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "ValueStream",
                    dataValueField: "Id",
                    dataSource: categories,
                    select: onSelect
                });
}
```

And this the other method from editor of the second ddl

```
function linesDropDownEditor(container, options) {

    $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataTextField: "Line",
                    dataValueField: "Id",
                    dataSource: lines
                });
}
```

So when I select an item of the first ddl I want to refresh the second ddl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `id` attribute for your second dropdown then in `onSelect` function of `ddVs` you can add this line of code.

`$("#nameOfYourSecondDropdownHere").data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.read();`

Comment: How I can put an Id to the dropdown? because it create automatically in the grid

Comment: Put it on the element the DDL will be initialized from, e.g.:

function linesDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input id="your-ID" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,...

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the following example - Cascading DropDownLists used as editors in Grid:

[Add Cascading DropDownList Editors](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/cascading-dropdown-editors)

Comment: Actually I tried this, and it works but only shows one value instead all of them with the same Id from cascade